# PHP script on web page is displaying python code instead of executing it

Tags: python, php, html

Nothing fancy, however I'm not sure what is wrong I've verified the .py works just fine on its own
Please send help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<form action="test1.py">
    <input type="submit" class="button" name="bob" value="cyan pulse">
<h1>test php</h1>

<button id= button1> Test Button
<?php
system ( "sudo python /var/www/html/test1.py" );
echo "lights have been turned on";
?>
</button >
<p>My first paragraph.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

EDIT:

After testing I found that the culprit of displaying the text is

```
<form action="test1.py">
    <input type="submit" class="button" name="bob" value="cyan pulse">
<h1>test php</h1>
```

Obviously I have a lot to learn in regards to PHP
This is mainly a hobby project that I have, 
The python script still isn't executing correctly.
I am aware of some sort of switch that you may add to the end in linux that can help show errors, however my understanding of it hasn't fully developed.

It may be a permissions error as well, Although I believe I have given www-data correct permissions, but I'm sure there is more to it than that.
Here is the updated code for reference

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<h1>test php</h1>

<button id= button1>Pulse Cyan
<?php
$Python=`python /var/www/html/test1.py`;
echo shell_exec ( $Python );
echo "lights have been turned on";
?>
</button >
<button id= button1> Turn LED off
<?php
$Python=`python /var/www/html/turnoffled.py`;
echo shell_exec ( $Python );
echo "lights have been turned on";
?>
</button >

<p>My first paragraph.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Update I have verified that the issue is in how shell_exec() is running
I have tested this pre and post enabling cgi with sudo a2enmod cgi
I have checked the php.ini for shell_exec being disabled (it wasn't)
Please if anyone has any *good* rabbit holes of research I can go down that would be great.

Comment: I'm surprised it prints anything at all given the use of sudo - I'd expect it would instead be waiting for someone to enter a password

Comment: What I'm curious about is am I trying to implement shell_exec()/exec()/system()/etc the incorrect way or is this more so linked to a permissions issue in python? 
Its as if it opens up the python file in a text editor.

Answer (score 0):

It was a permissions issue with www-data needed to be on sudoers, as well as allowing sudo in php. However this idea has been scrapped and I'm taking a different approach. 
Posting this in case someone else has the same struggle.